# Permission with maxSdk shows up as new permission on every app update on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have an app that uses the external storage to save some larger cache files in the directory provided by `getExternalCacheDir()`. Now since Android 4.4 the permission is no longer required to access this directory, so I decided to set a `maxSdk` for the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

But when I published an update for my app on the Google Play Store, the permission dialog showed the above permission as a *new* permission on Android KitKat and Lollipop, i.e. API level 19–22, even though it was supposed to not be requested on those versions:

[image]

When I look at the app details in the system settings, the permission is not listed, so the system seems to interpret the `maxSdk` attribute correctly.

How can I fix this? It's pretty bad that the users of my app have to accept this "new" permission on every update even though it's not needed at all...

Comment: +1. I tried to invite GenericBot to a few of my chat rooms but they didn't join, and now I'm hearing from someone that I need to get permission from the owner. Would you be able to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the Google Play Store as reported with [issue 63898](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63898) and [issue 63895](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63895), and it doesn't seem to be fixed yet.

So we can't do much about it, besides not using the `maxSdk` attribute or trying to avoid the permission in the first place.

At least it's no problem on Android 6.0 and newer versions that support runtime permissions, since the Play Store does not list any permissions at install-time here.